# ASCII to NSData

Tags: cocoa, nsdata, extended-ascii

This is another crack at my MD5 problem.  I know the issue is with the ASCII character © (0xa9, 169).  Either it is the way I am inserting the character into the string or its a higher vs lower byte problem.

If I

```
 NSString *source = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", 0xa9];

    NSData *data = [source dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"\n\n ############### source %@ \ndata desc %@", source, [data description]);

CC_MD5([data bytes], [data length], result);

     return [NSString stringWithFormat:
   @"%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x",
   result[0], result[1], result[2], result[3], 
   result[4], result[5], result[6], result[7],
   result[8], result[9], result[10], result[11],
   result[12], result[13], result[14], result[15]
   ];
```

Result:

######### source ©

[data description] = (null)
md5: d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e

values: int 169 char ©

When I change the encoding to

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:[source UTF8String] length:[source length]];
```

The result is

######### source ©

[data description] = "<"c2>
md5: 6465dad1d31752be3f3283e8f70feef7

When I change the encoding to

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:[source UTF8String] length:[source lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

The result is
 ############### source © len 2 
[data description] = "<"c2a9>
md5: a541ecda3d4c67f1151cad5075633423

When I run the same function in Java I get

">>>>> msg## \251 \251
  md5 a252c2c85a9e7756d5ba5da9949d57ed

The question is what is the best way to get the same byte in objC as I get in Java?

Comment: You don't need to send an object a `description` message and then pass that to `%@`. The `%@` formatter sends the object a `description` message for you.

Comment: You might consider reading http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html to get some basics on the difference between characters and bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to GBegan's explanation in another post I was able to cobble this together.

```
for(int c = 0; c < [s length]; c++){
    int number = [s characterAtIndex:c];
    unsigned char c[1];
    c[0] = (unsigned char)number;
    NSMutableData *oneByte = [NSMutableData dataWithBytes:&c length:1];
```

}

Answer (score 6):

“ASCII to NSData” makes no sense, because ASCII is an encoding; if you have encoded characters, then you have data.

An encoding is a transformation of ideal Unicode characters (code points) into one-or-more-byte units (code units), possibly in sequences such as UTF-16's surrogate pairs.

An NSString is more or less an ideal Unicode object. It contains the *characters* of the string, in Unicode, irrespective of any encoding*.

ASCII is an encoding. UTF-8 is also an encoding. When you ask the string for its `UTF8String`, you are asking it to encode its characters as UTF-8.

> ```
> NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:[source UTF8String] length:[source length]];
> ```
>
> The result is
>
> ```
>  ######### source ©
>  [data description] = "<"c2>
> ```

That's because you passed the wrong length. The string's length (in characters) is not the same as the number of code units (bytes, in this case) in some encoding.

The correct length is `strlen([source UTF8String])`, but it's easier for you and faster at run time to use `dataUsingEncoding:` to ask the string to create the NSData object for you.

> When I change the encoding to
>
> ```
> NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:[source UTF8String] length:[source lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
> ```

You didn't change the encoding. You're still encoding it as UTF-8.

Use `dataUsingEncoding:`.

> The question is what is the best way to get the same byte in objC as I get in Java?

Use the same encoding.

There is no such thing as “extended ASCII”. There are several different encodings that are based on (or at least compatible with) ASCII, including ISO 8859-1, ISO 8859-9, MacRoman, Windows codepage 1252, and UTF-8. You need to decide which one you mean and tell the string to encode its characters with that.

Better yet, continue using UTF-8—it is almost always the right choice for mostly-ASCII text—and change your Java code instead.

> ```
> NSData *data = [source dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
> ```
>
> Result:
>
> ```
> [data description] = (null)
> ```

True ASCII can only encode 128 possible characters. Unicode includes all of ASCII unchanged, so the first 128 code points in Unicode are what ASCII can encode. Anything else, ASCII cannot encode.

I've seen `NSASCIIStringEncoding` behave as equivalent to `NSISOLatin1StringEncoding` before; it sounds like they might have changed it to be a pure ASCII encoding, and if that's the case, that's a good thing. There is no copyright symbol in ASCII. What you see here is the correct result.

---

*This is not quite true; the characters are exposed as UTF-16, so any characters outside the Basic Multilingual Plane are exposed as surrogate pairs, not whole characters as they would be in a truly ideal string object. This is a trade-off. In Swift, the built-in String type is a perfect ideal Unicode object; characters are characters, never divided until encoded. But when working with NSString (whether in Swift or in Objective-C), as far as you are concerned, you should treat it as an ideal string.

Comment: Yes I am slowly becoming aware of the trials of my dilemma.  The problem is in Java 0xa9 is used in a MD5 hash and I get the same result as the server produces. I am porting the Java to objC 1st for the iPhone, then to OSX.  My goal is to send CC_MD5 a byte that will give me a result equal to the Java and server results.  At that point I believe my overall hashing problem will be solved.  This question is an attempt to solve the problem by attacking the odd element out.

Comment: Jim: The problem is that you are pretending `0xa9` is a character, when it is a byte. The solution is to work out what character you mean when you say `0xa9` in the Java code, then work out which encoding converts that character to the single byte `0xa9`, then use that character and that encoding in your Cocoa code.